# Adding withTrashed() to route only if user is admin

Tags: laravel

I use [withTrashed](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#implicit-soft-deleted-models) when defining my route.

```
Route::middleware('auth')->resource('post', 'PostController')->withTrashed();
```

Is there a way to add `withTrashed()` to a route only if the `Auth::user()->isAdmin()`?

Comment: You can't conditionally add withTrashed() directly in the route definition.

Comment: I think you'd need to move to [explicit bindings](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#customizing-the-resolution-logic) in that case.

Comment: potentially, you could write a middleware that runs before the `SubstituteBindings` middleware that could do the check and call `withTrashed` on the route bound to the current request so when it gets to the `SubstituteBindings` middleware it would have the correct property set to allow "trashed" models